# Is every archimedean absolute value over $\mathbb{C}$ complete?

Tags: field-theory, valuation-theory

By an absolute value over $\mathbb{C}$, I mean a function $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that:

$\bullet$ $|x| = 0\Longleftrightarrow x=0$;

$\bullet$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $|xy| = |x||y|$;

$\bullet$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$.

An archimedean absolute value is one that does not satisfy the stronger inequality "$|x+y|\le \max\{|x|,|y|\}$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$". A complete absolute value is one inducing a complete metric.

Now, the two following assertions are equivalent:

(i) every archimedean absolute value over $\mathbb{C}$ is complete;

(ii) for every archimedean absolute value $|\cdot|'$ over $\mathbb{C}$, there exists an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and $c\in (0,1]$ such that $|x|' = |\sigma(x)|^c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$, where $|\cdot|$ is the usual absolute value of $\mathbb{C}$.

((ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) is obvious. (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) follows from one of the two Ostrowski's theorems.)

So, I was wondering if (i) holds, that is, every archimedean absolute value over $\mathbb{C}$ being complete? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Counterexample: Pick a proper subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to it (these are known to exist) and consider the restriction of the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$ to this subfield.

Comment: How is $ii \implies i$ obvious? Does that not need $\sigma$ to be continuous?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Note that the topology defined by $\sigma$ is different from the usual one: if $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ in the usual topology, then $\{\sigma^{-1}(x_n)\}$ converges to $\sigma^{-1}(x)$ in the topology induced by the absolute value $|\sigma(\cdot)|$. Please tell me if I was wrong :)

Comment: @Rafi That works, thanks very much!

Comment: @Rafi a possible bonus question: ask the same question in ZF

Answer (score -1):

The question is then whether you can get a $\sigma$ which is not the identity or the complex conjugation.

If you have the axiom of choice you can construct wild automorphisms, e.g. get a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, permute it in such a way that one of its elements doesn't go to itself or its conjugate and extend the permutation to an automorphism.

If you don't have it, it is possible to have models of set theory where the only automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are the identity and the complex conjugation.

Comment: Sorry but that does not serve as an counterexample. For any $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$, the absolute value $|\sigma(\cdot)|$ is complete (inducing different topology from the usual one).